# mysql Group field name eliminating all non alpha characters

Tags: mysql, select, replace

i have a table with phone number entered as shown below

```
tel
--------
+6112345
611-12345
61112345
611 12345
```

All these are one phone number which has been entered in different ways. How can I write a query which will group all these into one?

I have written a query like -

```
select replace(replace(replace(tel,"+",""),"-","")," ",""), count(*)  
from tb_orders 
group by replace(replace(replace(tel,"+",""),"-","")," ","")
```

help me fix this please!

Comment: All no are not same First have 7 digits and all other has 8.

Answer (score 0):

Source data

```
SELECT * FROM tb_orders;
+-----------+
| tel       |
+-----------+
| +6112345  |
| 611-12345 |
| 61112345  |
| 611 12345 |
+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Query :

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tel,"+",""),"-","")," ","") AS PhoneNumber , COUNT(*) FROM tb_orders GROUP BY PhoneNumber;
+-------------+----------+
| PhoneNumber | COUNT(*) |
+-------------+----------+
| 61112345    |        3 |
| 6112345     |        1 |
+-------------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: yes i did in the same way , just want to know is there any other way for doing this